# MVC DisplayFor function - how do I find out which template is used?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following problem:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PkID)
```

(where PkID is of type long) fails with the following exception:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int64', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +378
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary.set_Model(Object value) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +614
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1..ctor(ViewDataDictionary viewDataDictionary) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.set_ViewData(ViewDataDictionary value) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +425
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate(HtmlHelper html, ViewDataDictionary viewData, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, GetViewNamesDelegate getViewNames, GetDefaultActionsDelegate getDefaultActions) +1037
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +1621
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +140
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression) +92
```

We have lots of DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates in our project and I am certain that one of them is used instead of the default, but I need to know which template is chosen (incorrectly) so that I can fix the content.

How do I find out which template was chosen by the framework? Using the call stack in Visual Studio 2013 didn't help because I only get decompiled Assembler code for the method that would have the template name (System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.ExecuteTemplate).

Comment: Do you have a template named Int64?

Comment: Yes, but only as an EditorTemplate and if I comment out the content, then I still get the exception so this one's not the template that is chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio, go to `Tools > Options > Debugging` and uncheck `Step over properties and operators (Managed Only)`

Then add a breakpoint on `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.PkID)`. It will probably step into lots of other stuff but will eventually end up in the template

Comment: Thank you, this sort of worked. It was the String template which was called, except that the problem was in the first line of that template and I didn't comment it out when I first tried: @model String. Changing the allowed model type to object worked great for now.

Comment: If you add a `Int64.cshtml` template to `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` it should always use this for type `long` rather than defaulting to String

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best way to determine which template is executed is to know how display and editor templates are handled in MVC framework. There are just a few different options you should check

- You explicitly specified template name in DisplayFor call (which is not the option in your case)
- You used [UIHintAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on `PkID` to instruct framework which template to use
- You have template under Views/ControllerName/DisplayTemplates
- You have template placed under Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates

Note that even if template is placed on plysical location but excluded from visual studio solution, it will still be rendered.

Comment: So there is no easy way getting the String templateName from the internal framework methods somehow? The first three options are not the case so it must be one of the templates under Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates. I just don't know which one, I already commented out the code of the most obvious ones (String.cshtml, Object.cshtml) and the exception was still thrown.